# Union of two subspaces versus intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

According to the definition, the union of two subspaces is not a subspace. That is easily proved to be true. For instance,

Let $U$ contain the general vector $(x,0)$, and $W$ contain the general vector $(0,y).$ 
Clearly, the union of these two subspaces would not be in either of the subspaces as it will violate closure axioms.

As for the intersection of the two subspaces, I believe I understand the concept. However, I want to be sure of that, and I believe it comes down to the difference between union and intersection as applied to vector/subspaces.

Basically, union - in this context - is being used to indicate that vectors can be taken from both subspaces, but when operated upon they have to be in *one or the other* subspace. Intersection, on the other hand, also means that vectors from both subspaces can be taken. But, a new subspace is formed by combining both subspaces into one.

To explain, I'll use the same subspaces as above. Let $U$ contain the general vector $(x,0)$, and $W$ contain the general vector $(0,y).$

So, the intersection of $U$ and $V$ would contain the general vector $(x,y)$ (I should say based on what I said above). Therefore, the closure axioms are fulfilled.

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning is wishy-washy, to put it nicely. What does "combining both subspaces into one" actually mean? If $(x,0)\in U$ and $(0,y)\in W$, it still *doesn't follow* that $(x,y)\in U\cap V$. You may be confusing the intersection with the span or sum of subspaces, $\langle V,W\rangle=V+W$, which is incidentally the subspace spanned by their set-theoretic union. If you want to know why the intersection of subspaces is itself a subspace, you need to get your hands dirty with the actual vector space axioms. Ultimately it boils down to logical and operations and implications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the intersection is the set of all vectors that are in both subspaces.  In your example, that would only be the vector $(0,0)$  For a less trivial example, in $\mathbb R^3$ let $U$ be all vectors of the form $(x,y,0)$ and $V$ be all vectors of the form $(0,y,z)$.  Then $U \cap V$ is all vectors of the form $(0,y,0)$.

Answer (score 14):

The *intersection* $A \cap B$ of two sets $A$ and $B$ contains only elements which are in *both* subsets. To verify that the intersection $W := U \cap V$ of two subspaces $U,V$ is a subspace, you need to check if for any two elements $a,b \in  W$ you also have $a+b \in W$, and similarly that for any element $a \in W$ and every scalar $\lambda \in K$ you have $\lambda a \in W$.

You do that by observing that if $a,b \in W$ then $a,b \in U$ *and* $a,b \in V$ because the intersection contains only elements that are in *both* sets. Now, since $a,b \in U$ you get $a+b \in U$ because $U$ is a subspace, and simiarly $a+b \in V$ because $V$ is also a subspace. Which then of course means $a+b \in W$, since $a+b$ lies in both of the intersected sets. The same line of reasoning works for the $\lambda a$ case.

Note that this a a very general principle - a lot of mathematical structures have the property that if $A$ and $B$ fulfill the structure's axioms then $A \cap B$ does too. And the proof very often basically works as in the case of subspaces above.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The intersection of two sets is the set of elements that are in both of them.  In your example the intersection is $\{(0,0)\}$.
The union is the set of elements that are in one, or the other, or both.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove that the **intersection** of two subspaces **is** also a subspace.

Assume that we have a vector space $V$ which has two subspaces $S$ and $T$ inside. We would like to prove that $S\ \cap\ T$ is also a subspace of $V$. So we can list the **assumptions** as given below:

1. $S$ is a subspace of $V$.
2. $T$ is a subspace of $V$.
3. $S\ \cap\ T$ is a subset (not subspace) of $V$.

we want to **prove** that that:

- $S\ \cap\ T$ is a subspace of $V$.

Based on assumptions 1 and 2 we can imply that all linear combinations of vectors inside $S$ reside in $S$, and that all linear combinations of vectors inside $T$ reside in $T$. Formally speaking:

$$ 
 \alpha x + \beta y \in S
$$ 
$$
 \gamma m + \theta n \in T
$$ 
where $x$ and $y$ are two random vectors in $S$ and $m$ and $n$ are two random vectors in $T$. $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\theta$ are real numbers. Based on the third assumption we can choose a set of vectors $x$ and $y$ which reside in both sets $S$ and $T$ and we can rewrite the above formalization as:
$$
  \alpha x + \beta y \in S
$$
$$
  \gamma x + \theta y \in T
$$
Simplifying the above formula, we can rewrite the case in which $\alpha$ is equal to $\gamma$ and $\beta$ is equal to $\theta$. In this case, we'll have:
$$
  \alpha x + \beta y \in T
$$
$$
  \alpha x + \beta y \in S
$$
This shows that linear combinations of two random vectors $x$ and $y$ reside in both sets $S$ and $T$. So these linear combinations will be definitely inside the intersection of $S$ and $T$ as well. 
$$
  \alpha x + \beta y \in S\ \cap\ T
$$
hence $S\ \cap\ T$ is just a cute little subspace.